# Периодический SQL запрос

Tags: mysql

Подскажите, как сделать периодическим SQL запрос, допустим, чтоб выполнялся один раз в сутки?

Comment: спасибо - можете ответить, я выберу как правильный ответ

Comment: @Semen  Savenko, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: я знаю как выбирать правильный ответ - но докладчик просто написал его в комментарии

Comment: @Seven Savenko, комментарий про галочку рядом с ответом был написан после того, как я преобразовал комментарий в ответ, дабы Вам на мыло упало сообщение и Вы зашли в вопрос :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Cron в помощь](http://prof-labs.ru/blog/mariadb-and-mysql/138).

Answer (score 0):

Для этого можно воспользоваться механизмом событий MySQL (EVENT)

```
CREATE EVENT `myevent`
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
  UPDATE tbl SET tiq = tiq + 1;
```