# Как правильно работать с событием EVENT

Tags: php, mysql

Есть переменная в базе данных переменная Bonys=0;
Как сделать чтобы допустим в 00 00 она у всех игроков стала равным 1.
Название таблицы users.
Создал файл 1.sql
Поместил туда код ниже,но ничего не срабатывает((

```
CREATE EVENT `myevent`
ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 minute
DO
  UPDATE users SET Bonus = 1;
```

Comment: Это три отдельных задачи: 1) составление sql-запросов; 2) подключение к mysql из php; 3) запуск команды в определённое время. По-моему, все три задачи уже расписаны в других вопросах на этом сайте

Comment: Надо перепроектировать БД таким образом что бы это было не нужно. А для этого надо постараться рассмотреть задачу с других сторон.

Comment: @Mike чем вас это не устроило?

Comment: Но если все таки очень хочется, то можно запланировать событие в БД, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/522605/194569

Comment: @andreymal Потому что любые периодические процессы не надежны. Может сервер не будет работать в заданное время срабатывания и пропустит событие. Или после сбоя диска развернут БД из дампа и она окажется не с том состоянии, которое было бы ожидаемо в текущее время. Или часы на зиму переведут и событие отработает дважды. P.S. А ваши 3 пункта уже давно устарели. Можно обойтись только первым пунктом и не привлекать php и cron. В MySQL есть встроенный планировщик

Comment: @Mike если вернуться в реальную жизнь и оценить возможную сложность задачи с заделом на будущее (бонусы випам, подарки в определённые даты, добавление бонусов пропорционально активности и т. п.), то может оказаться, что реализовать обработку описанных вами проблемных ситуаций будет проще, чем другие возможные варианты реализации. И одного лишь mysql для решения задачи может и не хватить по каким-либо причинам

Comment: @andreymal Любые задачи с бонусами должны решаться да, периодической задачей. только не в 00:00, а несколько раз в сутки. Скрипт должен сравнить текущее состояние БД с расчетным на момент запуска и доначислить все, чего не хватает. Этот же скрипт должен обязательно входить в перечень запускаемого при старте машины. тогда даже если из за какой то программной ошибки окажется что он не работал 2 дня ничего страшно не произойдет, он запустится и выполнит всю работу за оба дня

Comment: @andreymal Хотя если бы стояла задача тупо в 00 начислить всем бонус я бы положил в БД время последней выдачи бонуса и когда пользователь в следующий раз зайдет в игру посмотрел бы не пора ли выдать бонусы и сколько выдать. и на этом все. И не апдейтил бы тысячи записей каждую ночь. Из которых дай бог сотня зайдет в игру.

Comment: так получается crony нужно будет дать доступ к базе данных? то есть логин и пароль чтобы он мог зайти?

Comment: @Ivan912 Вам уже сказали - CRON в задаче не нужен, у MySQL есть собственный планировщик. Который Вы, кстати, используете, судя по CREATE EVENT. И которому логин и пароль не нужен - учётная запись, от имени которой будет выполняться эвент, задаётся в момент его создания в DEFINER clause (по умолчанию - CURRENT_USER).

Comment: @Akina спасибо)))) распишите ответ с планировщиком дам лучшего))))

Comment: Да чего там расписывать - всё просто и плоско, как блин. Шагаем по мануалу, и не проявляем ненужных инициатив. К тому же я целиком и полностью согласен с ранее высказавшимися товарищами - схема, которую Вы пытаетесь строить, идеологически косая. Особенно обратите внимание на комментарий Mike о том, что действие гораздо разумнее переместить в процедуру пост-аутентификации.

Comment: Нормальная схема.Тут плюс ,что сервер отдельно от пользователя контролирует бонусы.Сейчас сбои часто не встречаются ну нужно будет на практике смотреть.